# Value of a function at Jump Discontinuitiy?

Tags: functions, dirac-delta

How do you define value of unit step function $t=0$?

We know, 
$ u(t) =  0, t <0\\ $ and 
 $ 1, t>0$ but what should be the value of $u(0)$? I find both $u(0) = 0.5$ and $u(0) = 1$ are used in different places. But I would like to know how $u(0) = 0.5.$

Comment: For most uses of the step function, the value at $t=0$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to define Heaviside step function. Sometimes one takes $u(0) = 0.5$ to make the graph rotational symmetric. The definition one uses depends on what one needs. See [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Zero_argument) on Wikipedia  for more information.